# The implication of law of iterated expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Law of iterated expectation:  E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]

As $E[Y|X]$ is already a constant, would that mean that $E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]] = E[Y|X]$?

So $E[Y]=E[Y|X]$?

Or is there something I missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since when is $E(Y|X)$ constant? No... it is a RV *itself*.

Answer (score 0):

$E[Y|X]$ isn't a constant. It's a 'function' that depends on x: $E[Y|X=x]$. If you take the mean of $E[Y|X]$, the mean is taken over all values of x.

Comment: Isn't E[Y|X] itself about all x instead of one particular x?

Comment: It's the expected value of $Y$ when $X$ equals $x$. So it's about one particular $x$.

Comment: @Whatamidoing No, it's not explained well. ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X\mid \sigma (Y))=\operatorname {E} (X\mid Y)\circ Y}$ is downright wrong, for instance. If you define $f(y)=\operatorname {E} (X\mid Y=y)$,  then $\operatorname {E} (X\mid \sigma (Y))=f\circ Y$ would be correct. But I'm not surprised many can't see the difference, it is sort of abstract and obscure. In reality, the former is defined through the latter, but the Radon-Nikodym derivative is not an easy concept.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Is Whatamidoing right or wrong regarding E[Y|X]?

Comment: $\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (Y\mid X)$ is not the same as $\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (Y\mid X=x)$, as you can see from the mere fact that the former doesn't contain an $x$. It is a measurable function of $\color{red}X$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you. So what would your answer to my question be?

Comment: I said it already: it is a function of $X$, so it's not a constant, meaning your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you. However, what I don't get is that the distribution of the X should be fixed, so why it is not a constant?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Would this statement be correct "The law of iterated expectations implies that if the conditional mean of Y given X is zero, then the mean of Y is zero"?